# Not able to set state of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling to set the state of a dropdown menu

```
const options = [{ value: "Value1" }, { value: "Value2" }];
var option = [{ value: "Value1" }];

function changeValue(selectedOption) {    
  if (selectedOption && selectedOption.value != '-1')
  {
    var x = [];
    x.push(options[selectedOption]);
    option.value = x;
  }   
}    
<SelectDropdown currentValue={option.value} onChange={changeValue} options={options} />
```

`SelectDropdown` is a react component

Dropdown in UI has two values when you open the dropdown list but it will not set the state depending upon what has been selected?

The react component has the following `onChange`

```
onChange = (value) => {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
        this.props.onChange(value);
    }

    this.hideDropdown();
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you are not using state to update dropdown value you have to use `useState` hook to update state from of Dropdown

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([{ value: "Value1" }, { value: "Value2" }]);
const [option, setOption] = useState([{ value: "Value1" }]);

function changeValue(selectedOption) {    
  if (selectedOption && selectedOption.value != '-1') {
    setOption([value: options[selectedOption]])
  }   
}

<SelectDropdown currentValue={option.value} onChange={changeValue} options={options} />
```

When you Select Dropdown from `SelectDropdown` component then onChange will change state of option and updates the values in `SelectDropdown`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `[value:]` is giving an error for 'colon' after value... `Parsing error: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis.`